# Where is the FLT_MAX macro defined?

Tags: c, macros

I tried looking at the float.h header file and all I found was

```
#  define FLT32_MAX FLT_MAX
```

However, shouldn't it be

```
#  define FLT_MAX (some number)
```

but I can't find this kind of definition and so I wonder where would the defintion of the FLT_MAX macro be?

Comment: [cfloat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/)

Comment: @Achal In C++ it is there but that header does not exist in C.

Comment: It is in `float.h` (MSVC) with `#define FLT_MAX 3.402823466e+38F`.

Comment: I also looked in the float.h file and I can not even find FLT_MAX defined with a number o

Comment: It might be in another header included by your system's implementation of `<float.h>`. Or automatically defined by your compiler.

Comment: @shawn It might be in the files included by the float header file in my system

Comment: However the task of finding the macro is near impossible as it means I would need to explore each #include I come across

Comment: @shawn what is meant by automatically defined?

Comment: It's not unheard of for a compiler to automatically define a bunch of macros before it ever sees a single `#define`.

Comment: @duper21 : Searching files for text content is _trivial_ - that is one thing computers are good at! It would be foolish to manually open every file, and even then you don't need to open _every_ header file - only recurse through the nested headers included from float.h.   Moreover in an IDE such as Visual Studio, you need only right-click on the symbol and select "goto definition".  The actual location may vary between different toolchains, and you have not specified.  Really though, why do you need to know?

Comment: @clifford BTW I am using notepad so I can really learn the C environment well. The reason I'd like to know is because of curiosity.

Comment: @duper21 : That is a non-sequitur, wanting to use the tool chain at the command line level does not preclude using an editor capable of searching files recursively. Moreover, I'd suggest that you would learn more, faster and of greater importance with a decent debugger, and smart code browser. This question being a case in point. However if you insist in self-flagilation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find can be used to search all headers in your compiler's include directory recursively.

Comment: @duper21 I guess you missed my point about not specifying your tool chain.  You are likely to get Linux/GCC specific answers which may not help you and is a waste if other's time if that is not what you are using.  You need to add that information to your question.

Answer (score 7):

In C, the macro `FLT_MAX` is defined in the standard header `<float.h>`.

Examining a file named `float.h` on your system and not finding a definition of `FLT_MAX` doesn't prove anything. You might be looking at the wrong file. Conceivably `<float.h>` might not even be a file.

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("FLT_MAX = %g\n", FLT_MAX);
}
```

should compile and run without error. If it doesn't, your system is broken somehow. If it does, you may be able to coax your compiler to tell you where it found `<float.h>`. For example, if you're using gcc on a UNIX-like system:

`gcc -E` *filename.c* `| grep 'float\.h'`

The `<float.h>` header should *not* define a macro named `FLT32_MAX`, at least not in conforming mode. That's non-standard and it's in the user name space, so a program should be able to use that name for its own purposes.

Comment: if I have to compile with g++, how can I substitute FLT_MAX?

Comment: @ChanKim `#include <cfloat>` (though `#include <float.h>` should also work).

Comment: thanks. including <float.h> worked for me.